# SVG getBBox() for group element gives different result from a rect element with the same size and position

Tags: javascript, svg, bounding-box

I do getBBox() on a group element and on a rect element. The group element and the rect element have the same position and sizes. The groups getBBox() always give x,y as 0,0, while the rect gives its actual position in the outer group. Why is that so? Should the group element's getBBox() not just give back its bounds inside its parent element, as the rect element does?
The following html prints the following to the console:

```
SVGRect { x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 400}<br/>
SVGRect { x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100}<br/>
SVGRect { x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100}<br/>
```

```js
var superg = d3.select("#canvasHolder").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 400)
               .append("g").attr("id", "superg")
    
superg.append("rect").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 400).style("fill", "blue").style("fill-opacity", 0.2)
superg.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100).style("fill", "red").style("fill-opacity", 0.2).attr("id", "rect").attr("x", 100).attr("y", 200)
    
superg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100, 200)").attr("id", "g")
      .append("rect").attr("cx", 0).attr("cy", 0).attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100)
    
console.log(d3.select("#superg").node().getBBox())
console.log(d3.select("#g").node().getBBox())
console.log(d3.select("#rect").node().getBBox())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasHolder"></div>
```

I would have thought that the group element should have as x and y values the same as the rect element. Why is this not so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to look at the generated SVG to find the answer.  I'm going to concentrate on the inner `<g id="g">` and strip out the rest.

```
<g transform="translate(100, 200)" id="g">
  <rect cx="0" cy="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</g>
```

The bounding rect values you get back from calling `getBBox()` on an element **does not include the effect of any `transform`** attribute on that element.  It is calculated from the bounding boxes of its children only.

See: [the definition of getBBox() in the SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox)

So calling `getBBox()` on the group only includes the dimensions of its `<rect>` child, hence (0, 0, 100, 100).  But the `<rect>` *is* affected by the transform provided by it's parent, so you get (100, 200, 100, 100) when you get the bbox of that.

Comment: So the x and y values of the bbox for the group is never relative to an encapsulating element, it only shows the top left corner of its content relative to itself then?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, then yes.  The group is in a different coordinate space to the rect.  The rect is in a coordinate space created by the transform on its parent (the group). In the group's coordinate space, the rect is at 0,0. But in the rect's coordinate space, it is at 100,200